# multi-layered caching with ehcache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, dao, ehcache

A project I am working on, we have decided to implement ehcache for our caching purposes in our web based app. For the most part, we would be using it for Hibernate caching (of master tables) and query-caching.

However, we are also considering method caching at the DAO layer. Honestly, I am a bit skeptical about that. It could mean that say, we have a method at the DAO layer which in turn fires a query (which is already cached), would it make any sense to cache that method then? My feeling is that either we should cache the method OR cache the query that method eventually fires.

Please do let me know your inputs!

Comment: What do you mean by caching a method?

Comment: Object caching. Please take a look here: [link] (http://karlagius.com/2009/10/07/object-caching-in-java-with-ehcache/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience it very much depends on you application (and the kind / structure your data). The application I'm working currently on has 3 built-in layers of cache (all backed by Ehcache): one as Hibernate 2nd level cache, one for short termed hot objects at the middle tier and one for longer termed fat value object at the facade layer. The caches are tuned (cache query parameters, lifetimes, sizes, ...) to supplement each other well.

So a priori, I wouldn't say it doesn't work. There is a possiblity you can skip the entire ORM layer with that. If you have some profiling in place (I like [perf4j](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) for that) you can at least optimize for "hot" objects that are expensive to get from your DAOs. If you are using Spring Framework you can do this easily by applying e.g. `@Cacheable` annotations to your methods. Do your performance testing with (near) live data and requests if possible.

In fact, I think using Hibernate 2nd level cache is the easy / lazy thing to do (so to say a good first step), but the performance gains are limited. With some more specific caching you can easily get factors of hundreds or thousands as speedup for parts (hopefully the important ones) of you application, usually at reduced load.